# Ubuntu server 22.04 Postfix/Dovecot error: postfix/smtpd fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

Following the Ubuntu's official guide [Install and configure Postfix](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/mail-postfix), when I run

```
telnet localhost 25
```

I get

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

When I look into the logs I get

```
$ sudo tail /var/log/mail.err
Dec  7 11:38:17 <host> postfix/smtpd[8477]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

---

The above example is running in a virtual machine, but the same happens in a server in the cloud, and running `telnet` remotely to the domain. (I tried to replicate the process in the VM to see if I could spot what happens more easily).

I've read every post, blog, article, old and new, tried every configuration I could think of, and yet the error persists. I can't figure what is wrong. My configurations:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = <host>
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = <host>, <host>.local, <host>, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.30.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 4
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
```

**/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf**

```
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    #mode = 0666
    #user = 
    #group = 
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  #user = $default_internal_user
}
```

---

The SSL files in the VM I created following the official guide [Security - Certificates](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-certificates). In my cloud server I tried with Let's encrypt/Certbot files. I added them in the **/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf** file

```
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/server.key
```

I restarted both Postfix and Dovecot services after each change in configuration. The services state:

**Postfix**

```
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2023-12-07 12:26:07 UTC; 9min ago
       Docs: man:postfix(1)
    Process: 3362 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3362 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

dic 07 12:26:07 <host> systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
dic 07 12:26:07 <host> systemd[1]: Finished Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

**Dovecot**

```
● dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-12-07 12:26:08 UTC; 12min ago
       Docs: man:dovecot(1)
             https://doc.dovecot.org/
   Main PID: 3372 (dovecot)
     Status: "v2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a) running"
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 2220)
     Memory: 3.1M
        CPU: 44ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dovecot.service
             ├─3372 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F
             ├─3373 dovecot/anvil
             ├─3374 dovecot/log
             ├─3375 dovecot/config
             └─3381 dovecot/stats

dic 07 12:26:08 <host> systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
dic 07 12:26:08 <host> dovecot[3372]: master: Dovecot v2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
dic 07 12:26:08 <host> systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
```

---

I followed the *Troubleshooting* section in the guide. I tried many permutations, but nothing works, and the logs don't give any detail I can work with.

The question is already *too long*, and as I tried so many things I prefer not to make it longer, please ask in the comments and I will edit adding relevant information if needed. Maybe I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150470/discussion-on-question-by-schrodingerscatcuriosity-ubuntu-server-22-04-postfix-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Ubuntu guide**

One would expect from the [Ubuntu official guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/mail-postfix) that following the steps **S** will give the result **R** that can be tested with **T**, as that's how the guide is presented.

After doing **S** → **R** → **T**, my test failed, hence my confusion and the question posted here.

But, it happens that following **S** doesn't result in **R**:

The guide gives this configuration in **S**:

```bash
...
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext'
...
```

Notice the `noplaintext`.

The guide then says *"Outcome of initial configuration"*:

```bash
...
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
...
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
```

Notice **there's no** `noplaintext`, and also the `smtpd_tls_auth_only = no` that is not in **S** and is not in the default `postfix` configuration file (version 3.6.4).

So it happens that testing with `telnet` as suggested in the guide won't work if `noplaintext` is set, because it means that the communication must happen securely, and `telnet` doesn't support SSL.

From [www.postfix.org/SASL_README](https://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html)

> A more sophisticated policy allows plaintext mechanisms, but only over a TLS-encrypted connection:
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>        smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
>        smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
> ```

---

Tests:

- With `smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous` connecting with `telnet` will work:

  ```
  telnet <domain> 25
  ```
- With `smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext` connecting with `telnet` **won't work**.
- With `smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext` and `smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes` connecting with `openssl` will work.

  ```
  openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect <domain>:25
  ```
- With `smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext` and `smtpd_tls_auth_only = no` connecting with `openssl` **won't work**.

---

In summary, the Ubuntu guide is broken, at least for Ubuntu server 22.04, following **S** won't result in **R** so **T** will fail.

---

All this is acknowledge in the forum of the guide, even that the it should be rewritten, under the link [Help improve this document in the forum](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-and-configure-postfix/11325) (an account must be created to access). Here's a comment of one of the contributors:

> **Issue description**
>
> When using telnet `127.0.0.1 25`, `postfix` will apply
> `smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext` meaning that
> it will filter out `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` as they are are plain text
> mechanisms. Since `dovecot` was told to only enable those 2 (see
> `auth_mechanisms`), you have no other `SASL` mechanism to use… hence
> the fatal: `no SASL authentication mechanisms`.
>
> If however you connect with `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:25 -starttls smtp` you should see that `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` are both permitted because now you have an encrypted connection to the MTA so
> `smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous` applies. Since `PLAIN`
> and `LOGIN` are not annonymous, `postfix` doesn’t filter out any
> mechanism.
>
> The `noplaintext` directive can be confusing because it sounds like
> something we want to prevent leaking credentials in plain text.
> However, `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` are meant to be used on top of TLS
> meaning there is no actual plain text on the wire.
>
> **Best current practices**
>
> I think the guide would need to be refreshed to follow best current
> practices. SASL auth should not be enabled on TCP/25, only on TCP/465
> and TCP/587. It is best to leave port 25 for MTA to MTA (server to
> server) communication with opportunistic TLS and have users hit the
> smtps(TCP/465)/submission (TCP/587) ports where both TLS and
> authentication (SASL) are mandatory. Unfortunately, I don’t have time
> to do a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use the excellent postfix defaults. Rather follow official guides and create a minimal (and commented) configuration. The defaults for the above parameters are

```
postconf -d | grep -E "smtpd_sasl.*security_options"

smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
```